# Python code to find all fields in a document where the subfield matches a certain value

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Structure of my Firestore Database]

The picture above shows the structure of my firestore database.

I want to write a query in python that will retrieve all fields in the document "handOffInsulinByGatwork" in which the subfield "medDate" is equal to "2022-02-08T08:51".

I read the examples here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries, and wrote the query below. Unsurprisingly the query below is producing a blank list (it looks wrong even to my untrained eye).

```
testVar = db.collection(u'simmer').where('medDate', u'==', '2022-02-08T08:51').get()
```

What is the correct way to write a query to do the following: In the document "handOffInsulinByGatwork", retrieve all fields in which the subfield "medDate" is equal to "2022-02-08T08:51"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `medDate` fields seems to be *under* another field in your document. If that's the case, you'll need use dot syntax to address the nested field:

```
db.collection(u'simmer').where('medSubmutRestOfFieldName.medDate', u'==', '2022-02-08T08:51')
```